# How to get values in helmfile

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile, helm3

```
bases:
  - common.yaml


releases:
  - name: controller
    values:
      - values/controller-values.yaml
    hooks:
    - events: [ "presync" ]
    ....
    - events: [ "postsync" ]
    .....
```

common.yaml

```
environments:
  default:
    values:
      - values/common-values.yaml
```

common-values

```
a:b
```

I want to move the values of the hooks to file when I added it to common.values it worked but I want to add it to different files and not to the common, so I tried to add base

```
bases:
  - common.yaml
  - hooks.yaml

releases:
  - name: controller
    values:
      - values/controller-values.yaml
    hooks:
{{ toYaml .Values.hooks | indent 6 }}
```

hooks.yaml

```
environments:
  default:
    values:
      - values/hooks-values.yaml
```

hooks-values.yaml

```
hooks:
  - events: [ "presync" ]
    ....
  - events: [ "postsync" ]
    .....
```

but I got an error
parsing: template: stringTemplate:21:21: executing "stringTemplate" at <.Values.hooks>: map has no entry for key "hooks"

I tried also to change it o

```
hooks:
  - values/hooks-values.yaml
```

and I got an error
line 22: cannot unmarshal !!str `values/...` into event.Hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first issue is when specifying both `common.yaml` and `hooks.yaml` under `bases:`, they are not merged properly. Since they provide same keys, most probably the one that is included later under `bases:` overrides the other.

To solve that you can use a single entry in `bases` in helmfile:

```
bases:
  - common.yaml
```

and then add your value files to `common.yaml`:

```
environments:
  default:
    values:
      - values/common-values.yaml
      - values/hooks-values.yaml
```

I don't claim this is best practice, but it should work :)

The second issue is that `bases` is treated specially, [i.e. helmfile.yaml is rendered before base layering is processed](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/issues/1740#issuecomment-809278767), therefore your values (coming from `bases`) are not available at a point where you can reference them directly in the helmfile. If you embedded `environments` directly in the helmfile, it would be fine. But if you want to keep using `bases`, there seems to be couple of workarounds, and the simplest seemed to be adding `---` after `bases` as explained in the [next comment on the same thread](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/issues/1740#issuecomment-810576717).

So, a working version of your helmfile could be:

```
bases:
  - common.yaml

---

releases:
  - name: controller
    chart: stable/nginx
    version: 1.24.1
    values:
      - values/controller-values.yaml
    hooks:
      {{ toYaml .Values.hooks | nindent 6 }}
```

*PS: `chart: stable/nginx` is just chosen randomly to be able to `helmfile build`.*